# Detailed balance and Semi detailed balance in a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider the following transition matrix

$$
   T=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   \frac{1}{3}  & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6}\\
   \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} &  \frac{2}{6}\\
   \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{5}&  0\\
   0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0& \frac{3}{6}\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

of a Markov chain process
$$P_{t+1}=TP_t$$

The matrix $T$ is not symmetric, therefore I conclude that there is no detailed balance, and there is no equilibrium (the process is not reversible).

However, $T_{34}=T_{43}$.

Does this mean that there is semi-detailed balance?

what does it say about the equilibrium of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetry of the transition matrix is not a necessary condition for reversibility; consider $$P = \pmatrix{0&1/2&1/2\\1/4&1/2&1/4\\1/4&1/4&1/2}. $$
Since $P$ is irreducible and aperiodic, it has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ satisfying $\pi=\pi P$. Since $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$ we have the system of equations
\begin{align}
-\pi_1 + 1/4\pi_2 + 1/4\pi_3 &= 0\\
1/2\pi_1 -1/2\pi_2 +1/4\pi_3 &= 0\\
\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 &= 1,
\end{align}
which yields $\pi_1=1/5$, $\pi_2=2/5$, $\pi_3=2/5$. Let $P^\star_{ij}=(\pi_i/\pi_j)P_{ij},$ then 
$$
P^\star = \pmatrix{0&1/4&1/4\\1/2&1/2&1/4\\1/2&1/4&1/2} = P^T,
$$
so the detailed balance equations are satisfied and $P$ is reversible.

In general, $P$ is reversible if and only if $\Pi * P$ is symmetric, where $\Pi$ is the square matrix whose rows are identically $\pi$ and $*$ denotes component-wise multiplication (see [this thesis](http://web2.uwindsor.ca/math/hlynka/jiangmajorpaper2009aug11.pdf) for more details).

In your example, the stationary distribution for $S:=T^T$ is $$\pi = \pmatrix{33/137&36/137&50/137&18/137}. $$
(The transpose of $T$ is a row-stochastic matrix.)
We compute
$$
\Pi^T * S = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{33}{137} & \frac{33}{137} & \frac{33}{137} & \frac{33}{137} \\
 \frac{36}{137} & \frac{36}{137} & \frac{36}{137} & \frac{36}{137} \\
 \frac{50}{137} & \frac{50}{137} & \frac{50}{137} & \frac{50}{137} \\
 \frac{18}{137} & \frac{18}{137} & \frac{18}{137} & \frac{18}{137} \\
\end{array}
\right) * \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{3}{5} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{11}{137} & \frac{11}{137} & \frac{11}{137} & 0 \\
 \frac{9}{137} & \frac{9}{137} & \frac{9}{137} & \frac{9}{137} \\
 \frac{10}{137} & \frac{10}{137} & \frac{30}{137} & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{137} & \frac{6}{137} & 0 & \frac{9}{137} \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
which is not symmetric, and hence the Markov chain is not reversible.

For Markov chains, the semi-detailed balance condition is precisely the global balance condition $\pi = \pi P$.

Comment: you have a mistake in the normalization of the matrix, it is $\sqrt{5209}$ and not $137$. please correct, also in the follow up explanation about reversibility.